# How to remove tab spaces from response?

Tags: apex

I am trying to remove \t from my response

```
   General Information Requested           Sample \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tPriority\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tLow\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tIssue Description\t\t\t\t\t\tWorking\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tIssue Type\t\t\t\t\t\tChange\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tModule\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tenglish\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tReported By\t\t\t\t\t\t1234\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tSubmitted By\t\t\t\t\t\t8433\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tDate submited\t\t\t\t\t\t12/04/2016
```

this is my response from this i need to remove **\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t** 
i tried in this way but not working any one help on this

string some = something.replaceAll('\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\', ' ');

Thanks in Adavance

Answer (score 4):

Two problems are present in your code.

First, you're trying to replace literal tab characters, while replaceAll expects a regular expression. This means you need to double up on \ characters:

```
String some = something.replaceAll('\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t',' ');
```

Secondly, you can just replace any variable number of characters using a regular expression repeater:

```
String some = something.replaceAll('\\t+',' ');
```

This matters because there's not the same number of tab characters in each place in the string; you'd miss some of the tab characters.

Comment: The documentation claims it uses a regex, but I am fairly certain that is not consistent with the behavior I have observed.

Comment: @AdrianLarson It definitely does. Try this in execute anonymous: `System.debug('Hello World'.replaceAll('([aeiou])','$1$1'));` Output will be: "Heelloo Woorld".